# Solving a PDE with non-zero IC

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, integral-transforms, linear-pde

Given the function $f(x,t)$, solve the following PDE

$$\partial_{tt}f+ 2\partial_{t}f- \partial_{xx}f+f=0$$

BC: $$f(x=\pm \infty, t)=0$$
IC: $$f(x,t=0)=g(x), \quad f_t(x,t=0)=0$$

I tried solving it using FT in $x$

$$\partial_{tt}F+ 2\partial_{t}F-(1+w^2)F=0$$

then solving the characteristic equation

$$F=C_{1} \exp(-1+iw)+ C_{2} \exp(-1-iw)$$

Using the IC
$$F=G(w) \left(\frac{(iw+1) \exp(-1+iw) + (iw-1) \exp(-1-iw)}{2iw} \right)$$

after this I'm stuck because I couldn't inverse FT and find $f$
I appreciate any help I could get.

Comment: Can you please retype your question in LaTeX? I don't understand what you mean by "f_tt". Is it "$f_tt$"? "$f_{tt}$"?

Comment: yes that's what I meant sorry about that I've never used latex before, I will try to retype it

Comment: thank you! I fixed it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a shorter route. Defining $v(x,t)=e^tf(x,t)$, it is straightfoward to show that $v$ satisfies the wave equation $\partial_{tt}v-\partial_{xx}v=0$, which has the general solution $v(x,t)=u(x+t)+w(x-t)$, where $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary differentiable functions. Hence, the general solution to the original PDE is
$$
f(x,t)=e^{-t}[u(x+t)+w(x-t)]. \tag{1}
$$
The initial conditions yield the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
u(x)+w(x)=g(x), \\
u'(x)-w'(x)-u(x)-w(x)=0, \tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$
which has as solution
\begin{align}
u(x)&=\frac{1}{2}g(x)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x}g(\xi)\,d\xi, \tag{3a} \\
w(x)&=\frac{1}{2}g(x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{x_0}^{x}g(\xi)\,d\xi. \tag{3b}
\end{align}
Plugging $(3)$ into $(1)$, we finally obtain
$$
f(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\left(g(x+t)+g(x-t)+\int_{x-t}^{x+t}g(\xi)\,d\xi \right).
\tag{4}
$$

---

ADDENDUM

Let me complement my answer by showing how to arrive at Eq. $(4)$ from your partial solution. First, let's add a $t$ to the exponentials (which you forgot when you solved the equation $\partial_{tt}F+ 2\partial_{t}F-(1+w^2)F=0$), and rearrange terms:
\begin{align}
F(w,t)&=G(w) \frac{(iw+1) e^{(-1+iw)t} + (iw-1) e^{(-1-iw)t}}{2iw} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}G(w)\left[e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt}+\frac{1}{iw}
\left(e^{iwt}-e^{-iwt}\right)\right]. \tag{A.1}
\end{align}
From $(A.1)$ we obtain $f(x,t)$ as
$$
f(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(w,t)e^{iwx}dw
=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\left(I_1+I_2+I_3\right), \tag{A.2}
$$
where each $I_k$ corresponds to the integral of a term in $(A.1)$:
\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(w)e^{iw(x+t)}dw=g(x+t), \tag{A.3a} \\
I_2&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(w)e^{iw(x-t)}dw=g(x-t), \tag{A.3b} \\
I_3&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(w)\frac{1}{iw}\left(e^{iw(x+t)}-e^{iw(x-t)}\right)dw \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(w)\int_{x-t}^{x+t}e^{iw\xi}\,d\xi\, dw \\
&=\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G(w)e^{iw\xi}\,dw\,d\xi \\
&=\int_{x-t}^{x+t}g(\xi)\,d\xi. \tag{A.3c}
\end{align}
Combining $(A.2)$ and $(A.3)$ we obtain the solution $(4)$.

Comment: thank you that was really helpful ! but why doesn't the Fourier transform method work?

Comment: thank you so much!